# How to create/Initialize ArrayList of ArrayList using java Lambda

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

How to convert the following code to lambda in java8???

```
    List<List<String>> my2dList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        my2dList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.println("Counter: " +counter);
            my2dList.get(i).add(new String(""+counter));
            counter++;
        }
    }
```

expected result:

[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]]

Comment: Lambda is `(..) -> ..` and it is implementation of functional interfaces. Did you mean *streams* which would give same result? BTW your current code doesn't compile, and while we could guess what it is supposed to it would be nice to have its logic and expected result in question itself.

Comment: @Pshemo edited and yes using streams

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`IntStream.range(int startInclusive, int endExclusive)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to generate a stream of integers.

You can then use [`mapToObj(IntFunction<? extends U> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) to process those integers.

Finally, you can use [`collect(Collector<? super T,A,R> collector)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) to collect the values, e.g. to a `List` by using [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

```
List<List<String>> my2dList =
        IntStream.range(0, 5)
                 .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, 10)
                                         .mapToObj(j -> Integer.toString(i * 10 + j))
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to print the values as they are streamed, use [`peek(Consumer<? super T> action)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-).

If the `peek()` method should see the value as an `int`, you can split the expression in the `mapToObj` so you can peek at the intermediate value, before it is converted to `String`.

The conversion to `String` can then be done with a method reference, instead of a lambda.

```
                 .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(0, 10)
                                         .map(j -> i * 10 + j)
                                         .peek(val -> System.out.println("Counter: " + val))
                                         .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

Comment: Thank you!!This is great!! How to add counter to this code just like the example above?